# PDF popup in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have a PDF file generated through jsPDF. When the file opens in Mozilla, a popup windows appears as attached:
[image]

I would like to put some meaningful description there instead of "blob". How can I do it? What and where controls this input?
I had a look through posted topics here and also through the jsPDF script but there seems no answer to this.

Comment: Since Mozilla  is open source, why don't you look into the code to see if it is possible?

Comment: I am not a programmer so suggested solution above is no good for me. I hoped for someone skilled this could be a 3 mins solution / advice? Thanking anyone a lot :))))

Comment: I just noticed that "generated through jsPDF". So, anyone hacking the code should probably make changes to that & not to FireFox.

Comment: Thanks Mawg, for sure. My question remains how and where to change the code :)